# hive0.10.0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.EncodingUtils.setBit(BIZ)B

Tags: hive

could u help me? I use hive 0.10.0
hive> show tables;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.EncodingUtils.setBit(BIZ)B
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.api.Query.setStartedIsSet(Query.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.api.Query.setStarted(Query.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.QueryPlan.updateCountersInQueryPlan(QueryPlan.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.QueryPlan.getQueryPlan(QueryPlan.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.QueryPlan.toString(QueryPlan.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.history.HiveHistory.logPlanProgress(HiveHistory.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:973)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes because of incompatible "libthrift" jar version. So, I have downloaded the latest libthrift-0.9.3.jar, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. The version of Hive used is not compatible with Hadoop. The thrift version used by hadoop is different from the one used by hive. It good to use the compatible version of Hive or replace the thirft (jar) library used by Hadoop with one used by hive.

Answer (score 1):

When i faced this problem, this was my situation:

In `HADOOP_HOME/lib`, I placed `mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar`, which is not supposed to be there for some other excercises.

When I run Hive, it throwed me the same error like in your question.

I moved `mahout.X.y.jar` from `lib`, then started hive CLi and it worked like a charm.