# Pig script to read Cassandra table

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, thrift, datastax

Trying to write a Pig script that will extract data from a Cassandra table.  The Pig script looks like this:

```
REGISTER ./cassandra-all-2.0.8.39.jar
REGISTER ./datastax-agent-4.1.4-standalone.jar
REGISTER ./cassandra-driver-core-2.0.2.1.jar
REGISTER ./apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.12.jar

A = LOAD 'cql://username:password/mykeyspace/mycolumnfamily' 
    USING org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CqlStorage() 
    AS (user_id:long, fname:chararray, last_update_date:chararray, lname:chararray); 
DUMP A;
```

I keep getting following message:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ITransportFactory.supportedOptions()Ljava/util/Set

So far I’ve tried following version of ‘**cassandra-thrift**.jar’:  2.0.8.39, 2.0.12, 2.1.2.  None of them has helped.

Note:  Following environment variables have been set outside this script:

```
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=machine-name
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could that be related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465843/hive0-10-0-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-th)?

Comment: No. This was the one I was getting previously. One of the posts on Stackoverflow recommended using 'CqlStorage' instead of 'CassandraStorage'. Now in either case I get this one about 'ITransportFactory'.  Thanks.